# OpenGL ES - texture map all faces of an 8 vertex cube?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Working through some OpenGL-ES tutorials, using the Android emulator. I've gotten up to texture mapping and am having some trouble mapping to a cube. Is it possible to map a texture to all faces of a cube that has 8 vertices and 12 triangles for the 6 faces as described below?

```
// Use half as we are going for a 0,0,0 centre.
    width  /= 2;
    height /= 2;
    depth  /= 2;

    float vertices[] = { -width, -height, depth, // 0
                          width, -height, depth, // 1
                          width,  height, depth, // 2
                         -width,  height, depth, // 3
                         -width, -height, -depth, // 4
                          width, -height, -depth, // 5
                          width,  height, -depth, // 6
                         -width,  height, -depth, // 7
    };

    short indices[] = { 
            // Front
            0,1,2,
            0,2,3,
            // Back
            5,4,7,
            5,7,6,
            // Left
            4,0,3,
            4,3,7,
            // Right
            1,5,6,
            1,6,2,
            // Top
            3,2,6,
            3,6,7,
            // Bottom
            4,5,1,
            4,1,0,
    };

   float texCoords[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,

        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
```

I have gotten the front and back faces working correctly, however, none of the other faces are showing the texture.

[image]

Drawing code

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

    // Enable face culling.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);

    // What faces to remove with the face culling.
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
    // rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);

    if (normalsBuffer != null) {
        // Enabled the normal buffer for writing and to be used during rendering.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

        // Specifies the location and data format of an array of normals to use when rendering.
        gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalsBuffer);
    }

    // Set flat color
    gl.glColor4f(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);

    // Smooth color
    if ( colorBuffer != null ) {
        // Enable the color array buffer to be used during rendering.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        // Point out the where the color buffer is.
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
    }

    // Use textures?
    if ( textureBuffer != null) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    }

    // Translation and rotation before drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Disable face culling.
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be doing textures per-face instead of per-vertex. Can you post more of the drawing code so we can see how you tie these data sets together?

Comment: I have an example where they have used 24 vertices to define their cube. I believe this must be per-vertex and be the default? How do I specify per-face?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use 24 vertexes.  In OpenGL, a vertex is more than just position, it is the collection of all vertex attributes.  Every vertex array is accessed with the same index.

The infamous cube example is something almost everyone feels is inefficient when starting to use OpenGL, but in real-world, more complex models, the degree of duplication is quite low.

Comment: What do you mean you have to use 24 vertexes? If you have to duplicate the vertexes what is the point of using an index buffer then if you are still sending repeat data to the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

I have "only" modified  the GLES20TriangleRenderer.java file into the SDK example BasicGLSurfaceView, compile it and test it on two Android devices, an Android Phone and a Nexus 7 and this work good on the two devices :)

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.

   Modified by YLP (06 January 2014) for to handle a rotated texture mapped cube

 */

package com.example.android.basicglsurfaceview;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

class GLES20TriangleRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public GLES20TriangleRenderer(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        // mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        // mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

        mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeVerticesStrip.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mTriangleVertices.put(cubeVerticesStrip).position(0);

        mTriangleTexcoords = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cubeTexCoordsStrip.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mTriangleTexcoords.put(cubeTexCoordsStrip).position(0);

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
        // class's static methods instead.
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );
        GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL );
        GLES20.glDepthMask( true );

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        checkGlError("glUseProgram");

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

        // mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
        // GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        //        TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        // checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");

        // mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
        // GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
        // checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

        // GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        //         TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        // checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
        // GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
        // checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

        // From http://www.endodigital.com/opengl-es-2-0-on-the-iphone/part-fourteen-creating-the-cube
        // (but slighty modified)
        mTriangleVertices.position(0);
        // GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
           GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTriangleVertices);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);

        mTriangleTexcoords.position(0);
        // GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
           GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTriangleTexcoords);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
        float scale = 0.7f;

        Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);

        // YLP : add others movements cycles
        Matrix.rotateM(mMMatrix, 0, angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
        // Matrix.rotateM(mMMatrix, 0, angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
        // float scale = (float)( Math.abs( Math.sin( ((float)time) * (6.28f/4000.0f) ) ));
        Matrix.scaleM(mMMatrix, 0, scale, scale, scale);


        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        // Somes tests with only somes triangles
        // GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // worked initialy but only one triangle
        // GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // worked initialy but only two triangles
        // GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); // GL_QUADS does not exist in GL 2.0  :(
        // GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 8); // GL_QUADS does not exist in GL 2.0  :(

        // Draw the cube
        // TODO : make only one glDraWArrays() call instead one per face
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);

        checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
        // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
        // class's static methods instead.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
        // class's static methods instead.
        mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            return;
        }
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
        if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
        }
        maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
        if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
        }

        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
        if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
        }

        /*
         * Create our texture. This has to be done each time the
         * surface is created.
         */

        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

        mTextureID = textures[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

        InputStream is = mContext.getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.raw.robot);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
        if (shader != 0) {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
            int[] compiled = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
        return shader;
    }

    private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
        if (vertexShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
        if (pixelShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        if (program != 0) {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
            checkGlError("glAttachShader");
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
            int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
            if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                program = 0;
            }
        }
        return program;
    }

    private void checkGlError(String op) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_TEXCOORDS_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 2 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;

    private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData =
    {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V

           // initial triangle from the source
           // -1.0f,   -0.5f,          0,  -0.5f,   0.0f,
           //  1.0f,   -0.5f,          0,   1.5f,  -0.0f,
           // 0.0f,    1.11803399f,   0,   0.5f,   1.61803399f,

            // YLP : transform this to two triangles for to have a quad
            // -1, -1, 0,    0, 0,
            // 1, -1, 0,    1, 0,
            // -1,  1, 0,    0, 1,
            // 1,  1, 0,    1, 1,
            // -1,  1, 0,    0, 1,
            // 1, -1, 0,    1, 0

            // YLP :  use two quads with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP
            // Don't work because this make one accordeon effect :(
            -1, -1, -1,    0, 0,
             1, -1, -1,    1, 0,
            -1,  1, -1,    0, 1,
             1,  1, -1,    1, 1,
            -1, -1,  1,    0, 0,
             1, -1,  1,    1, 0,
            -1,  1,  1,    0, 1,
             1,  1,  1,    1, 1,
    };

    // From http://www.endodigital.com/opengl-es-2-0-on-the-iphone/part-fourteen-creating-the-cube/
    // (only moodify "static const GLfloat" to "private final float" on it)
    private final float cubeVerticesStrip[] = {
            // Front face
            -1,-1,1, 1,-1,1, -1,1,1, 1,1,1,
            // Right face
            1,-1,1, 1,-1,-1, 1,1,1, 1,1,-1,
            // Back face
            1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1, 1,1,-1, -1,1,-1,
            // Left face
            -1,-1,-1, -1,-1,1, -1,1,-1, -1,1,1,
            // Bottom face
            -1,-1,-1, 1,-1,-1, -1,-1,1, 1,-1,1,
            // Top face
            -1,1,1, 1,1,1, -1,1,-1, 1,1,-1

    };

    private final float cubeTexCoordsStrip[] = {
            // Front face
            0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1,
            // Right face
            0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1,
            // Back face
            0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1,
            // Left face
            0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1,
            // Bottom face
            0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1,
            // Top face
            0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1
    };

    private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;
    private FloatBuffer mTriangleTexcoords;

    private final String mVertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "}\n";

    private final String mFragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "}\n";

    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMMatrix2 = new float[16];

    private int mProgram;
    private int mTextureID;
    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int maPositionHandle;
    private int maTextureHandle;

    private Context mContext;
    private static String TAG = "GLES20TriangleRenderer";
}
```

=>  I managed to implement this in just a few hours and this work :)

==> so if Android is not the best platform, this seem however a really good and viable plateform for that I begin to play a little more with some multimédia developments on Android's devices :)