# OpenGL-ES Texture Atlas. t axis is inverted

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I'm mapping a texture from my texture atlas to a square on a cube. For some reason, the t axis is inverted with 0 being at the top and 1 being at the bottom. Any ideas why this is happening?

Also, I have to specify the texture coordinates in clockwise order rather than counter-clockwise. I am using counter-clockwise windings. The vertices, indices and texture coordinates I'm using are below.

```
 float vertices[] = { 
     // Front face
     -width, -height, depth, // 0
     width, -height, depth, // 1
     width,  height, depth, // 2
     -width,  height, depth, // 3

            // Back Face
            width, -height, -depth, // 4
          -width, -height, -depth, // 5
            -width,  height, -depth, // 6
            width,  height, -depth, // 7

            // Left face
            -width, -height, -depth, // 8
            -width, -height, depth, // 9
            -width,  height, depth, // 10
            -width,  height, -depth, // 11

            // Right face
            width, -height, depth, // 12
            width, -height, -depth, // 13
            width,  height, -depth, // 14
            width,  height, depth, // 15

            // Top face
            -width,  height, depth, // 16
            width,  height, depth, // 17
            width,  height, -depth, // 18
            -width,  height, -depth, // 19

            // Bottom face
          -width, -height, -depth, // 20
          width, -height, -depth, // 21
          width, -height, depth, // 22
          -width, -height, depth, // 23
    };

    short indices[] = { 
      // Front   // Back
      0,1,2, 0,2,3,  4,5,6, 4,6,7,
      // Left    // Right
      8,9,10, 8,10,11,  12,13,14, 12,14,15,
      // Top    // Bottom
      16,17,18, 16,18,19, 20,21,22, 20,22,23,
    };


    float textures[] = {
  // Front
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 0.25f,
        // Back
     0.25f, 0.0f, 0.50f, 0.0f, 0.50f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f,
        // Left
     0.50f, 0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 0.75f, 0.25f, 0.50f, 0.25f,
        // Right
     0.75f, 0.0f, 1f, 0.0f, 1f, 0.25f, 0.75f, 0.25f,
        // Top
     0.0f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.50f, 0.0f, 0.50f,
        // Bottom
     0.25f, 0.25f, 0.50f, 0.25f, 0.50f, 0.50f, 0.25f, 0.50f,
    };
```

My texture - a 256x256 .png file created in mspaint.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9a87120b99.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9a87120b99.png)

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? There are no question marks in your post. Below are general OpenGL tips (I'm not working with opengl-es):
If you're using indexed primitives, then you need only 8 (not 24) vertices to make a cube. Using more than 8 will make things needlessly complicated. If the texture is upside-down, problem could be in texture loading code (in the one that calls glBindTexture2D) - it is possible that bottom row of pixel is loaded first. Render/blit texture to screen in 2D to see if it is correct. 
Make sure you didn't break projection transform somewhere.

Comment: I'm using 24 vertices on advice from this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854237/opengl-es-texture-map-all-faces-of-an-8-vertex-cube/2854444#2854444. Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by render/blit the texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after yet more searching on the web, it seems that OpenGL assumes an image starts at the bottom scanline, meaning that you need to invert your y/t coordinates. Or use an upper left hand origin when looking at your original image.